# OpenNI launching error process[camera/driver-3]

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-launch, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I tried to launch

> roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

and got this error:

```
process[camera/driver-3]: started with pid [21833]
[ERROR] [1382523364.281865460]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/driver] of type [openni_camera/driver]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class openni_camera/driver with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus pcl/BAGReader pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VoxelGrid stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2
[FATAL] [1382523364.282295582]: Service call failed!
```

Anyone knows what's wrong? Kinect is not yet connected. I have Ubuntu 12.4 OS and ROS Hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93476/openni-launching-error-process%5Bcamera/driver-3%5D/) by [Wojciech](https://answers.ros.org/users/7006/wojciech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-10-23**:
Please state what software (OS and ROS) and versions you are using (use tags for that as well).

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-10-27**:
32 or 64bit? Did you install the openni packages (`sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you it worked after:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni*
```

Please close this question.

---

Originally posted by [Wojciech](https://answers.ros.org/users/7006/wojciech/) with karma: 66 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-04**:
To close a question, just accept an answer (click the checker sign below the answer's votes).